# How to change values in appSettings.json file based on environment

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am building API in .net core project and have to store some key value pairs in appSettings.json file for jwt token. For example i need to store valid issuer and valid audience. For development i have my appSettings.json file as below:

```
`{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "jwt": {
    "JwtIssuer": "https://localhost:44332/",
    "JwtAudience": "https://localhost:44332/",
    "JwtSecretKey": "my super secure key"
  }
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}`
```

For development environment this is fine but when i will have to deploy to say azure, do i need to change these URLs manually here in appSettings.json file or is there any other efficient way to manage these URLs that automatically gets updated based on environment.

Comment: You may look at [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Is correct. That's a way to go

Comment: yes i have looked into it and it seems very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default of ConfigurationBuilder is looking for `appsettings.<EnvironmentName>.json` file, so based on the environment that you are working with

when you are in IIS Express you are in Development and when you deploy your application your environment is Production. This is why you need `appsettings.Production.json`